# Why is it when you call toString() on a function using quokka, it returns a string with extra variables added?

Tags: javascript, quokka.js

I am teaching myself to use prototypes to extend the functionality of objects. I have hit a roadblock when it comes to functions though, when I log a function to string it returns something I don't understand. For example, given:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    return a + b
}
console.log( foo.toString() )
```

you get:

```
`function foo() { 
    var $_$c = $_$wf(1); 
    var a = ($_$w(1, 130, $_$c), 1); 
    var b = ($_$w(1, 131, $_$c), 2); 
    return $_$w(1, 132, $_$c), a + b; 
}`
```

I would expect to get:

```
`function foo() {
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    return a + b
}`
```

Why?

**Edit**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: executed your code in google chrome console and it returns the right result...

Comment: ah, I am using quokka to execute this code. so i guess quokka is adding those variables, I wonder why...

Comment: is your project using babel?

Comment: I have babel installed globally however It is not being used in the project. I'm only using quokka.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
    return a + b
}

console.log(foo);

let x = foo.toString();
console.log(typeof x) // This should return a string
```

When you print 'x' it should give you the code as a string too.

Comment: it gives function foo() { 
    var $_$c = $_$wf(1); 
    var a = ($_$w(1, 130, $_$c), 1); 
    var b = ($_$w(1, 131, $_$c), 2); 
    return $_$w(1, 132, $_$c), a + b; 
}

Comment: however the typeof x is string.

Comment: I used Visual Studio Code and Snippets from Google Chrome and return me a string like a normal function, did you try to prompt(x)?

Answer (score 0):

I try  this example it return

```html
`function foo() { 
    var $_$c = $_$wf(1); 
    var a = ($_$w(1, 130, $_$c), 1); 
    var b = ($_$w(1, 131, $_$c), 2); 
    return $_$w(1, 132, $_$c), a + b; 
}`
```

and then I made an object and put the function to it and try to return it as toString and also it work correctly

Comment: it says cannot find name $_$wf and cannot find name $_$c so these variables cannot be instantiated in the global object. Also I tried it using an IIFE and it couldn't find them either so they arn't instantiated by the environment on function execution either.